# How to make window open maximized in Processing

Tags: processing

I am trying to figure out how to make a window of Processing start out maximized, I made it so it is the correct size but it is off to the side a little.

Thanks in advance - Ian.

Comment: Why did this question get -3?

Comment: I did not voted, but [have you read this?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :) What have you tried? Show some code.

Answer (score 1):

I find this question good but there is lack of OP's initiation with searching. First hit with search query "processing full screen" gives very good information about this topic [here](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Window_Size_and_Full_Screen)

Basically solution is to set size of window according to width and height to display's then overwrite `sketchFullScreen` method:

```java
void setup() {
  size(displayWidth, displayHeight);
}

boolean sketchFullScreen() {
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Making a window the same size as the screen is not the same as making it maximized.

Answer (score 1):

Set the sketch to resizable, then use java calls to maximize.
The delay can be replaced with a wait for the window to become active.

```
import java.awt.*;


surface.setResizable(true);
delay(100);
javax.swing.JFrame jframe = (javax.swing.JFrame)((processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas)getSurface().getNative()).getFrame();
jframe.setLocation(0, 0);
jframe.setExtendedState(jframe.getExtendedState() | jframe.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Making window maximized with P2D (and maybe with P3D) renderer:

```java
void setup() {
    //arbitrary init size
    size(200, 200, P2D);
    com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow window = (com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow)(surface.getNative());
    window.setResizable(true);
    window.setMaximized(true, true);
    //get window width and height without window decorations
    println(window.getWidth(), window.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution but it crashes. If I remove window.setResizable(true), it expands the screen but crashes anyway